# Populate html Table from values of an json array using ng-if

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I have an array json as follows

```
$scope.array =[{"id":"1","age":"3","name":"ab"},{"id":"2","age":"2","name":"ee"},{"id":"3","age":"1","name":"dd"}];
```

I need to show these data in a table using ng-if where if the age is 1 then that cell should have only data related to age = 1 etc. I used the following code.

```
    <html>
    <table>
<tr>
<th>one</th>
<th>two</th>
<th>three</th>
<tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="record in array">
    <td ng-if="record.age == '1'">{{record.id}} {{record.name}}</td>
    <td ng-if="record.age == '2'">{{record.id}} {{record.name}}</td>
    <td ng-if="record.age == '3'">{{record.id}} {{record.name}}</td>
    </table>
    </html>
```

But currently all the values are shown in the first column one after the other. I can't figure out the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to close your **tr** tag with an end tag. Something like this:

```
<tr>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>two</th>
    <th>three</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="record in array">
        <td ng-if="record.age == '1'">{{record.id}} {{record.name}}</td>
        <td ng-if="record.age == '2'">{{record.id}} {{record.name}}</td>
        <td ng-if="record.age == '3'">{{record.id}} {{record.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

However, in your case, you won't gain nothing by using ng-if. You will get the same output if you use the following code:

```
<tr>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>two</th>
    <th>three</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="record in array">
        <td>{{record.id}} {{record.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

If you really want to use a ng-if, the way that you're doing is fine.

Comment: What if I want to check a condition and display the values if the data fullfill the condition?

Comment: Using the second approach like I mentioned before, you can always do something like <td ng-if="bananas == true"> true string </td> <td ng-if="bananas == false"> false string </td>